# Cannot Use CURL on /etc/pam.d/sshd

Tags: linux, centos, shell, pam, curl

I am creating a script that doing cURL everytime SSH login happens. 
I inserted a new line in /etc/pam.d/sshd like this:

`auth       required     pam_exec.so /bin/curl.sh`

and my curl script is like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

myVar=$(/usr/bin/curl http://127.0.0.1:8081)
echo $myVar >> /tmp/hai
whereis curl >> /tmp/hai
```

The problem is, the output of `/tmp/hai` only records the output of `whereis curl` only, not with `curl`

```
[root@loc-4 l-user]# tail -f /tmp/hai 

curl: /usr/bin/curl /usr/share/man/man1/curl.1.gz
```

Anyone knows why this is happened ?

Edited: I tried to run the script manually, and `curl` happened

Comment: Is the content of `$myVar` what you expect if you do this manually? What if you run the whole script manually? If there is an error while running `curl`, it will by default go to stderr and will not be captured into the variable.

Comment: There is an empty line in your `/tmp/hai`! So `$myVar` don't contain anything (even spaces).

Comment: @Sven when I ran that manually, the script worked

Comment: @F.Hauri yes, but nothing happened on the curl process

Comment: @WilliamsPerdana Redirect STDERR (and STDOUT) into temporary files to make some light on your problem!  See [my answer](https://serverfault.com/a/976934/142978)!

Answer (score 1):

#### Care about *`ENVIRONMENT`*!

Show differences between environment of regular login sessions and environment for daemon like pam.

Change you line in `/etc/pam.d/sshd` for `session` instead of `auth`:

```
auth      required     pam_exec.so /usr/local/sbin/nssh.sh auth
session   optional     pam_exec.so /usr/local/sbin/nssh.sh session
```

And change your script, try this (and end them with `true` in order to prevent login reject due to wrong result code):

```
#!/bin/bash

printf -v myfile "/tmp/nssh-%(%Y%02m%02d%H%M%S)T-%04X" -1 $$
exec 1>$myfile.log
exec 2>$myfile.err
echo $0 -- $@
set

if [ "$PAM_TYPE" = "open_session" ] ;then
    myVar=$(/usr/bin/curl http://127.0.0.1:8081)
    echo $myVar >> /tmp/hai
    whereis curl >> /tmp/hai
fi

true
```

This will redirect STDERR and STDOUT in separated scripts, then print in `.log` command line and arguments, then environment.

So you will be able to compare environment for regular session (manual run) and those created from PAMd.

Comment: Answer edited!! (.. and tested ;-)... Sorry I could'nt test you `curl` line :-p

Answer (score 0):

One possible answer is the `env` is different with a `pam_exec`. Example variables to consider are `$HTTP_PROXY` or `$NO_PROXY`. Searching for `.curlrc` config file uses `$HOME` or `$CURL_HOME`.

For example, your manual run can succeed because of `NO_PROXY=127.0.0.1`. Then the pam-initiated run simply returns HTTP 403 which curl doesn't reveal by default. I'd suggest to first run `curl -v` in your script, so that you know where you've connected and what HTTP numerical response you've got.